# Upper and lower case in Python

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase

I want to do a program where I have this input: New Word
and this output: NeW wOrD

```
def changeCase():
i=0
while i <= len(word):
    if((i%2)==0):
    print(word[i].upper())
else:
    print(word[i].lower()
    i=i+1
```

Comment: If that's your actual code, then your indentation (the tabs) are off.

Comment: You've got some code here.  So what is the problem?  If the code isn't doing what you want, you have to **show us** what it does, and **explain** how that isn't what you wanted.

Comment: So I basically want to the odd is upper case and the par a lower case. that's what I'm trying here...

Comment: I want to do a program where I have this input: New Word and this output: NeW wOrD

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to take the word as a parameter, and the indentation inside the function needs to be corrected.

```
def changeCase():  # needs "word" parameter
i=0  # needs to be indented to be inside function
while i <= len(word):
    if((i%2)==0):
    print(word[i].upper())  # needs to be indented to be inside if:
else:  # needs to be indented to match the if:
    print(word[i].lower()  # missing a closing )
    i=i+1  # needs to be un-indented to be outside else:
```

With those fixes we have:

```
def changeCase(word):
    i=0
    while i <= len(word):
        if((i%2)==0):
            print(word[i].upper())
        else:
            print(word[i].lower())
        i=i+1

changeCase("New Word")
```

That gets us:

```
N
e
W

W
o
R
d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\python\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    changeCase("New Word")
  File "C:\test\python\test.py", line 5, in changeCase
    print(word[i].upper())
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is because the valid range of indices in a sequence is one *less than* the `len` (because the indices start at zero).

Changing `while i <= len(word)` to `while i < len(word)` fixes the `IndexError`, but we still are printing each letter on one line.  We can fix that by adding `end=''` to our `print` calls, and adding a final `print()` at the end to add the finishing newline:

```
def changeCase(word):
    i=0
    while i < len(word):
        if((i%2)==0):
            print(word[i].upper(), end='')
        else:
            print(word[i].lower(), end='')
        i=i+1
    print()

changeCase("New Word")
```

gives us:

```
NeW WoRd
```

But we still have the problem here that we're alternating the case on every character, and based on the example it seems like we only want to alternate on every *letter*.  So we don't want `i` to be the index of the character in the string, we want it to be the current count of alphabetical characters.  To handle that it's probably easiest if we change our `while` loop to a `for` loop over the characters in the string, and only increment `i` if the character is alphabetical:

```
def changeCase(word):
    i = 0
    for c in word:
        if i % 2:
            print(c.lower(), end='')
        else:
            print(c.upper(), end='')
        i += c.isalpha()
    print()

changeCase("New Word")  # NeW wOrD
```

Comment: Hey, Sam
Thank you so much for your help, but I just did the wrong output
the one that I want to do is NeW wOrD. Could you help me with it? I don't know if I'm in the right path.

Comment: Ah, I see -- the way to accomplish that, I think, would be to have a variable that you only increment when the letter `isalpha()`.  Probably easier to do with a `for` loop over the string.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost correct! Try out the following code, and see if it works for you!

```py
def changeCase(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if((i%2)==0):
            print(word[i].upper())
        else:
            print(word[i].lower())

changeCase("hello world")
```

How does it work?

Inside the `changeCase()` function, we create a for loop (it's easier than a while loop). The loop counts up by 1 each iteration until it reaches the end of the word.
We then check if the current iteration / letter (stored in `i`) is even. If it is, print the letter in upper case. If it isn't (`else`), print the lowercase form of the letter.
Finally, call the function with whatever text you want!

Answer (score 0):

Other than some typos/minor errors, then main issue with your code is that `print` inserts a newline after each call. Fixing this (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)), one could do:

```py
def changeCase(word):
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if not i%2:
            print(word[i].upper(), end="")
        else:
            print(word[i].lower(), end="")
        i += 1

word = "New Word"

changeCase(word)
NeW WoRd
```

If you want to ignore blank spaces, then instead you can do:

```
def changeCase(word):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if not j%2:  # use j counter
            print(word[i].upper(), end="")
        else:
            print(word[i].lower(), end="")

        # only increment j if not a space character
        if word[i] != " ":
            j += 1
        i += 1
```

This gives:

```py
word = "New Word"
changeCase(word)
NeW wOrD
```

Comment: Hey, Matt Thank you so much for your help, but I just did the wrong output the one that I want to do is NeW wOrD. Could you help me with it? I don't know if I'm on the right path.

Comment: @GustavoDutra I've added further to the answer to get the output you require.